# MySQL - calling several stored procedures in a specific order

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've built several stored procedures in MySQL.  I would like to run them in a specific order to ensure that tables are updated properly and efficiently.  What would be the best way to call the procedures to run in a specific order?  I would like to have them run once every 30 minutes or so.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

After some research, I found that a recurring event for each procedure is a good way to go.  Creating each event about 10 seconds apart ensures they run in sequence every 30 minutes.

```
CREATE EVENT `[Event_Name]`
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 MINUTE
    DO
      CALL `[Stored_Procedure_Name]`();
```

Comment: What happens if the first one fails? Or the middle one? This doesn’t seem like a very robust solution.

Comment: They shouldn't fail.  They are simple procedures with INSERT and UPDATE statements mainly.  Nothing is really affected even if one was to fail.  The dashboard I have running will show the latest information if successful.  Otherwise, I can go back and check.

Comment: Reading the docs it seems that you have the first running every 30 minutes, the second every 31 minutes and the third every 33 minutes. I’m not sure that’s what you want?

Comment: Thanks, you're right.  I edited. Creating them separately every 10 seconds or so with 30 minutes interval each would do the trick.

Comment: I’m not convinced this “ensures” anything. I reckon a bit of a pause or slowness in one task and the others will overtake it. Unless you don’t really care whether the tasks run or what order they run in this is not an appropriate solution.